# TableCell/TableRow Margin programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, flowdocument

This has to be something super simple but it is driving me insane.  I have a Table that is created programmatically.  The `Table` has multiple rows and I want to control the spacing between each row.  I figured that changing the `Paragraph` `Margin` would do the trick but the Cell still has a margin. This is what I am doing;

```
Table tb = new Table();
tb.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
tb.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(new Run("A"));
p1.Margin = new Thickness(0);
tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell(p1));
tb.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(tr);
tr = new TableRow();
p1 = new Paragraph(new Run("A"));
p1.Margin = new Thickness(0);
tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell(p1));
tb.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(tr);
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(tb);
```

I tried to create a TableCell object and set the `Padding = new Thickness(0);` but this did not have any effect.

Note: I can be hard to see the extra space. If you add two Paragraph with a Margin of 0 you will see in fact there is space difference;

```
p1 = new Paragraph(new Run("B"));
p1.Margin = new Thickness(0);
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(p1);
p1 = new Paragraph(new Run("B"));
p1.Margin = new Thickness(0);
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(p1);
```

[image]

**edit:** it was suggested it was an issue with different sizes in the numbers verse letters.  So I changed the both examples to be letters to show the same thing occurs.

**edit 2:** reply to Ed Plunkett:  Your XMAL example does me no good as this needs to be programmatically created.  However, I did take your idea and does make it much clearer that the cell or the row is adding a space.  I added a red to the first Paragraph than gold to the second;

[image]

Comment: Depending on font, numerals may take up less vertical space than capital letters.

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett  I changed the both to letters to show this is not the case

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see what you mean.

Comment: Try setting CellSpacing=0 on the table. Looks like it defaults to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it's a simple fix:

```
Table tb = new Table() { CellSpacing = 0 };
```

And here's my reasoning. It looks like `Table.CellSpacing` defaults to 2:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
            <FlowDocument.Blocks>
                <Table x:Name="MyTable">
                    <Table.Columns>
                        <TableColumn />
                    </Table.Columns>
                    <Table.RowGroups>
                        <TableRowGroup>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell Background="Pink">
                                    <Paragraph Background="LightBlue">
                                        <Run Background="PaleGoldenrod">0123456789Aj</Run>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell Background="Pink">
                                    <Paragraph Background="LightBlue">
                                        <Run Background="PaleGoldenrod">0123456789Aj</Run>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableRowGroup>
                    </Table.RowGroups>
                </Table>
                <Paragraph Background="LightSkyBlue" Margin="0">
                    <Run>0123456789Aj</Run>
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph Background="LightSkyBlue" Margin="0">
                    <Run>0123456789Aj</Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument.Blocks>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <Label Content="{Binding CellSpacing, ElementName=MyTable}" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

So if I set it to zero in XAML...

```
<Table x:Name="MyTable" CellSpacing="0">
```

[image]

Comment: @Xaphann Awesome!